# Make database libraries and installation files accessible from outside Docker container?

Tags: docker

I am using Docker containers as a quick and easy way to deploy a test database on a machine. This all works fine and I can connect to the databases via other products and READ/WRITE to the databases.

On rare occasions I need access to the databases libraries and installation files for instance when I re-link a static runtime.

Is there a way to give access to the installation files in the container, to the host machine?

I guess if this is not possible, on these rare occasions, I would have to revert to installing the database properly on the host. It would just speed things up dramatically if this was possible via Docker containers because they are so convenient.

I've tried bind mounts and that gives me access to the data written to the database but not the installation files itself. I run into the issue described here at "Mount into a non-empty directory on the container" - https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/ Is there a way to reverse the bind mount so that I am mounting a directory inside the Docker container on my host machine rather than the other way around?

This is all probably in direct conflict with the point of Docker but if it works then it would save so much time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the files of the docker container, using the cp command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/
Does this help?

Comment: Hmm quite possibly. Another alternative that works OK (not ideal but better than a full dev install) was to test my product inside the container and re-link from within it.

But thanks that might just work.